Can I use Granite with the GTK Python Bindings
I was learning how to build a Gtk4 app in python (with this tutorial).
And I was wondering, is it possible to use the granite library in a PyGTK4 app ?
I am particularly interested in using the CSS classes of the elementary style sheet.
